# Visual Studio keeps adding a new line at the end of file on ctrl + save

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I read about "LF will be replaced by CRLF" warning, but even after `git commit`, the line is still there and it is showing up in my pull requests. So, I'm having unrelated files in my PR with just a line at the end of the file.

Here is snapshot of what is happing on hitting a ctrl+save on **any** file I open in my Visual Studio.
[image]
Is there anyway to disable to this?

Comment: Do you have `.editorconfig` in this project? It is usually configured via and entry there.

Comment: Thank you so much, someone recently added `.editorconfig` file and set a `insert_final_newline = true`. Removing that solved my problem

Comment: maybe add that as an answer and accept? It might help some future seekers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@pawel answered in comments above. The setting came from an `.editorconfig` file that was recently added.